# How to run laravel project in locahost from my computer to another computer?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I was copied my laravel project to run another computer. But this project does not work. So who can help me?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. The simple answer is that the two computers are different, and therefore any difference could be the cause of the problem. You should start by figuring out all the packages installed on the first system, and compare with the second system. For example, do they have the same version of Apache? Same version of PHP? Same version of MySQL (or some other database). Providing some diagnostic information about what is "not working" such as error messages, will allow people to answer your question more specifically. Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: If your question is actually "how can I always run my project on any computer without having to install everything exactly" you should look at the various container/virtual machine solutions available, for example Docker, or Vagrant.

Comment: Who was vote up like that question :< ....